# SetState is causing Futurebuilder to reload the data on every tap

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using future builder and stream builder to fetch data from firebase and show them on screen.
I have favourite button as well. when I click on favourite_borderLine iconButton. It fetch data from firebase then change the state to favourite_border iconButton.
It also change the state of every other listview.Builder what I want is just to change the icon state on every click not fetching the whole data from database.

This is the initial state
[image]

when I tap on favourite icon, Suppose I tapped on first icon then it start loading.
[image]

and then all the icons are changed :(
[image]

I just want to change the clicked icon state not all icons and do not want the fetch data on click just change the state of button.Here is code.

```
class TalentScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TalentScreen1State createState() => _TalentScreen1State();
}

class _TalentScreen1State extends State<TalentScreen1> {
  bool toggle = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<TalentFavCubit>(
      create: (context) => TalentFavCubit(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Talent Screen 1 home search'),
                  _retriveAllDocs,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _retriveAllDocs => FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: FirebaseRepo.instance.fetchWorkerFormFieldsData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("Nothing to show");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final List<DocumentSnapshot> data = snapshot.data.docs;
          return theUserInfo(data);
        }

        return Text("loading");
      });

  Widget theUserInfo(List<DocumentSnapshot> data) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              future: fetch(data[index]['uid']),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("Something went wrong");
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  TalentHireFavModel userData = TalentHireFavModel.fromMap(
                      data[index].data(), snapshot.data.data());
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(userData.name),
                        Text(userData.categories),
                        Text(userData.skills),
                        Text(userData.country),
                        Text(userData.phoneNo),
                        Text(userData.hourlyRate),
                        Text(userData.professionalOverview),
                        Text(userData.skills),
                        Text(userData.expert),
                        Text(userData.createdAt),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: toggle
                                ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border)
                                : Icon(
                              Icons.favorite,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // Here we changing the icon.
                                toggle = !toggle;
                              });
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }

                return Container();
              });
        });
  }
//TODO: Implementation Fix Error
  Widget _iconButton(uid) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseRepo.instance.fetchCurrentUserFavourites().snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
       var data = snapshot.data.docs;
        // print(snapshot.data.get('uid'));
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        return IconButton(
            icon: data.isEmpty == uid
                ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
                : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            onPressed: () =>
                BlocProvider.of<TalentFavCubit>(context).addTalentFav(uid));
      },
    );
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> fetch(data) async =>
      await FirebaseRepo.instance.fetchWorkerUserData(data);
}
```

Comment: Their state changes at the same time because they are all in the same StatefulWidget or they all share the same state in the state object. One way to resolve this is by giving them their own _state_. All you will need to do is pass the index down to the new Widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your broken line of code:

```
future: FirebaseRepo.instance.fetchWorkerFormFieldsData(),
```

The FutureBuilder documentation starts with:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

> A general guideline is to assume that every build method could get called every frame, and to treat omitted calls as an optimization.

And you broke the contract.  I have a video that illustrates this in detail. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg

Do what the docs say.  TL;DR: *Do not create the Future in the parameter to FutureBuilder.*

Comment: Yes I have applied your solution and it is not fetching data again. But when i click on favourite icon it chang the state of all icons in the listview builder